# How to get the sh formatter up and running?

Tags: bash, go, sh

The goal is to set up formatting for bash scripts (**.sh** files). So I'm trying to play around with the [.sh formatter](https://github.com/mvdan/sh). From the project's github quick start section; I have go installed and have pulled in the **shfmt module** like so: `GO111MODULE=on go get mvdan.cc/sh/v3/cmd/shfmt`. But on trying to invoke the **shfmt command**. I'm getting the common **command not found error**. How do I actually use the **shfmt command**. My assumption is this is plug and play i.e. I don't need to actually go and fiddle around with **PATHs** or **ENVs**.

Comment: @Volker thanks for pointing that out. I'll try out Peter's answer and look into this issue. Pheeew!!! I didn't expect the onslaught of downvotes, y'all are a tough crowd up in here lol!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is installed as `$HOME/go/bin/shfmt` (unless GOBIN is set, then it's `$GOBIN/shfmt`):

```
$ go help install
usage: go install [-i] [build flags] [packages]

Install compiles and installs the packages named by the import paths.

Executables are installed in the directory named by the GOBIN environment
variable, which defaults to $GOPATH/bin or $HOME/go/bin if the GOPATH
environment variable is not set.
```

Answer (score 1):

The installation happens with a help of `go install` command as Peter mentioned. I would like to make a step by step that worked for me on Windows 7 machine, because I bet there are some of you who don't know anything about go language and don't even want to hear about it:

1. Install go language from golang.org (I used installer for Windows of course)
2. Download [.sh formatter](https://github.com/mvdan/sh) and unzip it somewhere
3. Navigate to the root directory ..\sh-master with your favourite terminal (I use [GitBash](https://git-scm.com/) or you can use cmd.exe which every Windows has by default)
4. Run command `go install` and installation should start
5. Once installation is done, through terminal (GitBash or cmd) navigate to $HOME/go/bin (on Windows by default it's under C:\Users\your_username\go\bin)
6. From here you can use the shfmt command like so `shfmt -l -w yourBashScript.sh`
7. Voila! now your bash script yourBashScript.sh is modified and formatted)